# fsck.hfsplus cannot repair keys out of order

Tags: fsck, hfs+

My MacBook pro suddenly was no longer able to boot. Going into the disk utility from the recovery boot I tried to repair the drive and it failed saying that keys were out of order. I then made a copy of the entire drive and moved it over to an external drive. Using fsck.hfsplus I got the same error (I know disk utility essentially uses the same thing.)

The strange thing is that I can mount the .dmg and browse my files and nothing seems particularly out of order. However, 2/3 times I mount the image if I run ls on the root of the image I get . is an invalid directory.

I don't want to format the original drive until I'm sure I've repaired the image. Any suggestions on how to do this?